# zmq is not working with cx_freeze

Tags: python, windows, zeromq, cx-freeze

I'm trying to freeze a piece of python code, which imports a module that uses zmq, using cx_freeze. It's able to build the exe properly, but when I try to run it, it gives me the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\notebook\nbextensions.py", line 18, in <module>
    from urllib.request import urlretrieve
  File "c:\Python\64-bit\3.4\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 2237, in _find_and_load
  File "c:\Python\64-bit\3.4\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 2226, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "c:\Python\64-bit\3.4\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 1191, in _load_unlocked
  File "c:\Python\64-bit\3.4\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 1161, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "C:\Python34\lib\urllib\request.py", line 88, in <module>
    import http.client
  File "c:\Python\64-bit\3.4\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 2237, in _find_and_load
  File "c:\Python\64-bit\3.4\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 2226, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "c:\Python\64-bit\3.4\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 1191, in _load_unlocked
  File "c:\Python\64-bit\3.4\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 1161, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "C:\Python34\lib\http\client.py", line 69, in <module>
    import email.parser
  File "c:\Python\64-bit\3.4\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 2237, in _find_and_load
  File "c:\Python\64-bit\3.4\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 2226, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "c:\Python\64-bit\3.4\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 1191, in _load_unlocked
  File "c:\Python\64-bit\3.4\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 1161, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "C:\Python34\lib\email\parser.py", line 12, in <module>
    from email.feedparser import FeedParser, BytesFeedParser
  File "c:\Python\64-bit\3.4\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 2237, in _find_and_load
  File "c:\Python\64-bit\3.4\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 2226, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "c:\Python\64-bit\3.4\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 1191, in _load_unlocked
  File "c:\Python\64-bit\3.4\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 1161, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "C:\Python34\lib\email\feedparser.py", line 27, in <module>
    from email import message
  File "c:\Python\64-bit\3.4\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 2284, in _handle_fromlist
  File "c:\Python\64-bit\3.4\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 321, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "c:\Python\64-bit\3.4\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 2237, in _find_and_load
  File "c:\Python\64-bit\3.4\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 2226, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "c:\Python\64-bit\3.4\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 1191, in _load_unlocked
  File "c:\Python\64-bit\3.4\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 1161, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "C:\Python34\lib\email\message.py", line 16, in <module>
    from email import utils
  File "c:\Python\64-bit\3.4\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 2284, in _handle_fromlist
  File "c:\Python\64-bit\3.4\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 321, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "c:\Python\64-bit\3.4\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 2237, in _find_and_load
  File "c:\Python\64-bit\3.4\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 2226, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "c:\Python\64-bit\3.4\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 1191, in _load_unlocked
  File "c:\Python\64-bit\3.4\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 1161, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "C:\Python34\lib\email\utils.py", line 29, in <module>
    import socket
  File "c:\Python\64-bit\3.4\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 2237, in _find_and_load
  File "c:\Python\64-bit\3.4\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 2226, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "c:\Python\64-bit\3.4\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 1191, in _load_unlocked
  File "c:\Python\64-bit\3.4\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 1161, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "c:\Python\64-bit\3.4\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 539, in _check_name_wrapper
  File "c:\Python\64-bit\3.4\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 1715, in load_module
  File "c:\Python\64-bit\3.4\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 321, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "zmq\backend\cython\context.pxd", line 26, in init zmq.backend.cython.socket (zmq\backend\cython\socket.c:10554)
  File "c:\Python\64-bit\3.4\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 2237, in _find_and_load
  File "c:\Python\64-bit\3.4\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 2212, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "c:\Python\64-bit\3.4\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 321, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "c:\Python\64-bit\3.4\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 2334, in __import__
  File "c:\Python\64-bit\3.4\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 2254, in _gcd_import
  File "c:\Python\64-bit\3.4\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 2237, in _find_and_load
  File "c:\Python\64-bit\3.4\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 2212, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "c:\Python\64-bit\3.4\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 321, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "c:\Python\64-bit\3.4\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 2254, in _gcd_import
  File "c:\Python\64-bit\3.4\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 2237, in _find_and_load
  File "c:\Python\64-bit\3.4\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 2212, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "c:\Python\64-bit\3.4\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 321, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "c:\Python\64-bit\3.4\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 2254, in _gcd_import
  File "c:\Python\64-bit\3.4\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 2237, in _find_and_load
  File "c:\Python\64-bit\3.4\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 2226, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "c:\Python\64-bit\3.4\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 1191, in _load_unlocked
  File "c:\Python\64-bit\3.4\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 1161, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\zmq\__init__.py", line 34, in <module>
    from zmq import backend
  File "c:\Python\64-bit\3.4\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 2284, in _handle_fromlist
  File "c:\Python\64-bit\3.4\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 321, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "c:\Python\64-bit\3.4\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 2237, in _find_and_load
  File "c:\Python\64-bit\3.4\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 2226, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "c:\Python\64-bit\3.4\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 1191, in _load_unlocked
  File "c:\Python\64-bit\3.4\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 1161, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\zmq\backend\__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    reraise(*exc_info)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\zmq\utils\sixcerpt.py", line 34, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\zmq\backend\__init__.py", line 27, in <module>
    _ns = select_backend(first)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\zmq\backend\select.py", line 27, in select_backend
    mod = __import__(name, fromlist=public_api)
  File "c:\Python\64-bit\3.4\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 2237, in _find_and_load
  File "c:\Python\64-bit\3.4\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 2226, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "c:\Python\64-bit\3.4\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 1191, in _load_unlocked
  File "c:\Python\64-bit\3.4\lib\importlib\_bootstrap.py", line 1161, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\zmq\backend\cython\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from . import (constants, error, message, context,
ImportError: cannot import name 'socket'
```

For some reason, the `socket` module that has to be imported is being searched for in the zmq.backend.cython, rather than the standard python library. Any idea why this is happening?

Here is my setup.py, if that would help:

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

buildOptions = dict(packages = ['nb2kg', 'zmq', 'zmq.backend.cython', 'zmq.backend.cffi', 'urllib'], excludes = [])
base = 'Console'

executables = [
    Executable('C:\\Users\\XYZ\\Run Scripts.py', base=base, targetName = 'ABC.exe')
]

setup(name='ABC',
      version = '0.0',
      description = '',
      options = dict(build_exe = buildOptions),
      executables = executables)
```